# Increase max-height of div on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I want increase the **height** of a div from 0px to a max-height of 250px as the user scrolls. What is the best way to achieve this?

The closest I could get is using **scale** which doesn't really achieve the effect I need.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var mass = Math.min(2.5, 1+0.005*$(this).scrollTop());

        $('#expandable').css('transform', 'scale(' + mass + ')');
    });
});
```

Example: https://ceremonycoffee.com/ - note the white veil height increases as you scroll.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the `height` property?

Comment: guessing your 0.005 is sensitive to YOUR particular screen size too...that might be a concern

Comment: Just pointing out that in the example you provided they're increasing the `max-height`. You can also use `transform: translateY()` if you can set the parent element to `overflow-y: hidden`.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for stuff  [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ex92bp67/)

Comment: I think that'll do it, volt. Cheers!